# How to enhance the radial edges of an image

Tags: image-processing

I have an image as follows:

[image]

I want to **enhance (not binarize)** only the radial edges passing through the center so that it should look like this

[image]

**EDIT:** Following the suggestion of J. M. I applied the Sharpen[] to the image and below is the result

[image]

It seems to be on the right track. However, the center is quite darkened and the surrounding is a bit noisy. So, further improvement is required.

Comment: What does `Sharpen[]` do to your image?

Comment: I am planning to apply a line structuring element centered at the center of the image and rotate the line throughout and organize the possible pixels that may constitute such a radial line when fall on the rotating line should get enhanced as a line. Will this be a good idea. Even if this be, I don't know how to implement this so that I can give it a try.

Comment: I don't know much about image processing, so this is just a rough idea that might not work at all.  You could take the radon transform, apply vertical sharpening, then do an inverse transform.  Something along the lines of `InverseRadon@Sharpen[ImageAdjust@Radon[img], {0, 5}]`.

Comment: Or maybe try to mask everything but the lines going through the centre in the radon transform.  `col = Table[
   Clip[Exp[-(0.03 x)^2], {$MinMachineNumber, Infinity}], {x, -724/2.,
     724/2}];
mask = Image@Transpose@ConstantArray[col, 805];`  then `ImageAdjust@InverseRadon@ImageAdjust@ImageMultiply[Radon@img, mask]`.  Again, I have no idea what I am doing here, so no answer, only comment.

Comment: @Szabolcs: No, it's not providing any acceptable improvement.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to define a bit more quantitatively what you mean by "enhance". Also, it is pretty clear from the example that the angular edges are being emphasized, not radial. (The features are radial, but their edges are perpendicular to the feature direction.) A good approach may be to transform the image so that the radial and angular directions become horizontal and vertical, then do the processing operation (e.g. deconvolution/high pass filter with a one-dimensional kernel), and transform back afterwards.

Comment: Potentially related WC thread: "[Intensity radial profile in circular images](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/603459)."